# How to use in points or score in context of exam result?

Tags: word-in-context

If I had exam and I was asked about my result and I want to refer to it, then what is the correct way for that purpose?

> I've got 95 **score** out of 100.
>
> I've got 95 **points** out of 100.

Is it consider a correct way to refer to my results in such way or maybe there other way/s that sound/s natural in standard English.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I got a score of 95 out of 100.

and

> I got 95 points out of 100.

"score" refers to the overall result (95 correct answers out of 100 possible), while "points" is actually counting the correct answers (each correct answer being a "point").

Also I don't see any reason to use perfect tenses here, and it doesn't seem natural with them.